# SSRS - calulcate sum of rows in a separate column

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible using SSRS report (Tablix) to generate a report in the following format. The details need to be maintained while the total amount needs to be displayed in merged cells.

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired RepOutput]

**Current Output**

To my existing report i added a group under details. What i got was that the row collapsed into a single record as below

[image: Current Report Output]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you miss anything?

Comment: What research have you already done? What things have you already tried and what happened when you tried them which didn't work? Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking questions people will want to answer.

Comment: If you have a group on the `Name`, then it should be a simple `Sum`. Not positive on the Merged Cells though.

Comment: @3N1GM4 : added a group under details. What i got was that the row collapsed into a single record. What i am trying to achieve is to have merged cells with the sum while the other transaction rows are not collapsed.

Comment: @Binesh add this information  (ideally with real/illustrative examples) to your question and more people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get this in the format you require.

You are grouping by TransactionID then by the separate amounts (I used a rowID for this to get a unique ID to group on), which means that at the point where you want the merged cells you are grouping by a unique transaction amount. You cannot then group back out to TransactionID.

You can swap the fields over - the total before the amount column. This will work, but likely look wrong for your requirements.

Have a read about data regions (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156394(v=sql.100).aspx) and grouping (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx) to understand more about the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and confirmation.